# Stack Exchange & Area 51 sign up/ log in update

Tags: discussion, openid, announcements, authentication

As of today, [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) and [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) no longer have separate login and signup pages. When you log in or sign up on either site you will be sent  through meta.stackexchange.com flow. Currently, https://openid.stackexchange.com/ is still on the internet, but we are in the process of completely removing it.

As a part of our removal of OpenID. Learn more here: [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018)

Comment: So that means that users who log in directly on stackexchange.com will no longer have a physical profile there that would need to be deleted by staff if the user deletes all their Stack Exchange accounts?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Ultimately yes. We need to do some work to automate the clean up, but that is on our list.

Comment: Yes, but all users who currently don't have physical profiles there, who log in to stackexchange.com today, will not have a physical profile?

Comment: Will SEDE ever have a merged login?

Comment: @JohnLocke I doubt it as SEDE is open source and the universal login doesn't have a public API so there is no way for us to even start planning that work (yes, SEDE codebase isn't maintained by SE, it is only hosted and operated on SE severs)