# Cannot sign up to Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, openid, sign-up

I cannot sign up to Area 51. The error is

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

An unexpected error occurred while logging in.
It's not you, it's us.
This is our fault.
Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
```

Is there a fix?
I am signing up with my StackExchange account.
I selected sign up from the menu.

Related: [Unable to log in on Area 51 using Stack Exchange ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315814) (not a duplicate because of the request is completed and the error happened again.)

I am getting a 404 when I try to sign up on the Area 51 meta. (url that shows 404: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm)

Comment: Related/possibly dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315814 (looks like the same case, but possibly need SE staff to fix it)

Comment: @Bookends The linked one is status-completed which means another fix needs to be implemented to the system. But still related.

Comment: Long story short... there's currently an issue with Area 51 signups for users who are a member of a Team on Stack Overflow. I'm looking into a fix, but it's gonna take a bit - unfortunately setting up a test case for this locally is non-trivial due to how Area 51 works.

Comment: @AdamLear I am a team member. I think the error because of this.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Yep :) I'll let you know when it's fixed. Hopefully next week.

Comment: @AdamLear Is this fixed? I cannot sign-up still.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Fixed now!

Comment: Broken again now