# Area 51 login/signup links broken again

Tags: support, area-51, login, regression

The [login](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login)/signup links redirect to:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3dlogin&cdl=1`

This page sits like this, not redirecting:

[image]

This appears to be a recurring problem that’s been fixed and regressed several times:

- ["No login found" error trying to log in at Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319150/no-login-found-error-trying-to-log-in-at-area-51)
- [Is Area51 login broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323745/is-area51-login-broken)
- [Cannot sign up to Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324649/cannot-sign-up-to-area-51)
- [Unable to post - login problems with Area 51 ... again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245828/unable-to-post-login-problems-with-area-51-again)
- Many other [OpenID-related issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5barea-51%5d%20openid&searchOn=3) preventing login

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I tried signing in in a private window and was still able to do so - the page redirected for me just fine. (And I didn't select any cookie choices.)

Comment: @Sonic the OP was last seen in Area51 long ago (May 1 '15 at 21:38) so probably something changed since then in his provider or something like that, and Area51 old login mechanism can't handle it - I suspect they just "fix" it case-by-case for each user, when it's reported.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda In that case, the author has to contact SE to have it fixed.

Comment: @Sonic or, like past cases show, post a bug report here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Wow, almost a decade since I last logged in!

Comment: All the linked reports don't really have anything to do with the particular problem you're reporting. If you open the console in your browser (usually F12), are there any errors reported there? It's a JS redirect, so sitting on that page means something failed or was blocked client-side. Especially given there is extra code in there that attempts to detect if something failed and unhides a link to manually redirect - I'm guessing there's a JS error that is terminating code execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the [AdGuard](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/adguard-adblock-privacy/id1047223162) content blocker for Safari on iOS.

To temporarily fix:

Aa > Turn Off Content Blockers

To permanently fix:

Aa > Website Settings > Toggle *Use Content Blockers* off