# Unable to login Area51 for more than a year

Tags: support, area-51, login

Earlier I faced a [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315814/260388) which [was solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317056/260388) but this time I have been facing another error.

Following screen is shown when I press on `log in` link:

[image]

Following screen is shown when I press on `sign up` screen:

[image]

I have tried following things which didn't help:

- Update web browser
- Clear cache and data of web browser
- Disabling addons

I have been facing this issue for very long time, about a year. I was hoping that the problem should be solved eventually but it didn't happen. Recently I have tried to gather mass and advertised for one site/community proposal. I fear that we will fail if can't participate in Area51 soon.

Any idea or work-around how can I overcome this problem? Or I have to forget Area51 exists!

Software Information: Firefox Quantum 60.9.0**esr** (64-bit) and Chromium Version 76.0.3809.100 on Debian 10 GNU/Linux.

---

I just checked that my Area51 profile seems detached from my Stack Exchange profile at all. Following are some weird findings:

- My [Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4140743/pandya?tab=accounts) doesn't list Area51!
- My [account on Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/142143/pandya) redirects to [another network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/15776711/pandya?tab=accounts) ID which looks completely isolated.

Btw, I've reported the problem via [contact us](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form.

Comment: Try Incognito/Guest mode of the browser then log in. If your existing credentials won't work, just create a new Area 51 account then at some point it may be merged if you want. Edit: noticed Area 51 redirect here to MSE to create new account. Still, try creating it, and you should be able to take part, even if using a different account.

Comment: For search, a text version of the error messages might help future visitors who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like attempting to log into A51 back in April somehow created a brand new network account for you. How? Why? A mystery I'm not sure how to solve at the moment. The best guess I have is that you perhaps used a different login credential when you were routed through Meta Stack Exchange to log in?

Either way. I merged the two accounts, so you should be all set going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response with solution. I've just logged in successfully!

Comment: Btw, can you [delete the profile](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/205796/pandya-is-unable-to-login) I've created temporarily yesterday?

Comment: @Pandya Sure thing, done.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as Pandya was, do you think it's possible that the same thing's happened to me? (my [Area51 profile](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/223445/cdr), my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/26742364/cdr)) | If it is, is there anything I can do to fix it? (I contacted support a few days ago)

Comment: @CDR Dunno if exactly the same, but certainly similar. Your account should be all set. Thanks for your patience, and please let me know if you're still seeing issues.

Comment: @AdamLear - didn't realize you'd seen my comment, but yes, it works now, thanks!